# How to get notified about external changes in a mongo collection with sails?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I am developing an application based on mongo and sails, and i am testing how the realtime update in sails works.

I am using sails 0.9.16 now, but i am interested also in answers about sails 0.10.

I want a list to be updated when new documents are created in the corresponding collection. This works when i add documents via sails sockets, sending a post message. In that case i see other clients receiving a message and the list on the client side is updated.

There is an external service writing on the mongo database tough, so the collection is growing all the times. The new elements created directly by the external service in the database are not notified to listening clients, so i have to refresh the web page in order to show those elements.

Questions:

- are notifications about database creations supposed to work, when those creations do not come from sails itself?
- if yes, does this require some special configuration?
- if not, what would be a recommended way to keep client side listing about a collection updated when the database is changing?

Cheers

Comment: Any example on how the client are alerted of each new creation using sails socket ? When a new record is created in db, you get the event with mongo-watcher, but how to you send this events to the open sockets ?

Comment: The example is in a comment to the answer below, i will copy it here https://github.com/sourcefabric-innovation/citizendesk-interface/commit/e60ae0eb73fbe28309b9a2afef526849e9513380

Comment: I got this one. I tried mongo-watch and this is working fine. I was more concern about the publishCreate part. What does an incoming socket to be able to be notified via a publishCreate and how can the async events sent by the server be handled on the browser's side ?

Comment: In the controller receiving my request, I've done a MYMODEL.subscribe(req.socket), but when I'm doing MYMODEL.publishCreate(event.data); the socket on client side does not seems to receive the event. Any idea ?

Comment: You don't need `subscribe` in the controller, the blueprint API will do, but you have to subscribe on the client, using `get` on the collection and then listening on messages. Anyway, i can just suggest to open a new question for this

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this. Just last thing, I guess my pb was to listen to the message. Which event type does the publishCreate sends (socket.on('create', ...)) ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't remember precisely, this code worked: https://github.com/sourcefabric-innovation/citizendesk-frontend/blob/last-sails/app/scripts/services/monitors.js#L19 (registering for listening) and https://github.com/sourcefabric-innovation/citizendesk-frontend/blob/last-sails/app/scripts/services/monitors.js#L26 (handling the message). God bless free software. Using the debugger on the client side can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting question, though not an unusual one: the guys from [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) were having the same problem. Basically, without watching the DB you can't even scale your app horizontally, since one server process will have no idea on what data changes were made by another one.

So, at first they sort of patched it by polling the DB every 10 seconds. :) Obviously, it wasn't the best solution, so they ended up with another one (which can also work for Sails): now they are tailing the MongoDB [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) and fire an update whenever there's a change in the corresponding collection.

That said, to answer your questions:

- AFAIK, a Sails process has no clue about any external changes made to the DB;
- so, nothing to configure;
- a way to track external DB (MongoDB) updates would be using one of the oplog watchers you can find in npm (e.g. [this](https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch) or one of [these](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/oplog), etc.) to listen to the changes and trigger updates whenever there's a need.

Unfortunately, no ready-to-use solution here, but I hope at least that now you have an idea on how to make it work.

Comment: Hey, it works like a charm! https://github.com/sourcefabric-innovation/citizendesk-interface/commit/e60ae0eb73fbe28309b9a2afef526849e9513380 thanks a lot!

Comment: Uhm, i have a problem now, automated tests are failing. Since you are the author of barrels, you will probably have some suggestions that i could hardly find out by myself. Here there is the dedicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428907/how-to-run-sails-tests-when-a-mongo-oplog-is-watched