# How to run Sails tests when a mongo oplog is watched?

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I added [mongo-watch](https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch) to my Sails application, in order to detect external changes into the mongo database, following [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23087584/393758). This worked pretty fine, but now [my automated tests fail](https://travis-ci.org/sourcefabric-innovation/citizendesk-interface/builds/24100967). Probably because the barrels fixtures do not support the mongo watcher. Is there a way to set up the fixtures in Sails also when the database is watched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use Mongo on Travis, and it's not started by default. ;)

Seems like this can be the answer to your problem:

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MongoDB

Comment: In other words, while barrels mocks mongo, `mongo-watch` will not, thus it has to be handled separately. Cheers!

Comment: Barrels, actually, was made more for integration tests, so it doesn't mock Mongo, it creates real entries, but in the test database. Your problem here was purely Travis-related.